# C# Linq To SQL to Fill a DataGrid and and get fields into a TextBox

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

In C# i can easily get data from a SQL DataBase and put it in a DataGrid with this code :

```
 private void GetPcListBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string service = (string)ServiceCB.SelectedValue;          
        comm = new SqlCommand("select T_COLLABORATEURS.CO_IDENT,T_PC.PC_ID,T_PC.PC_NOM,T_PC.PC_MODEL," +
            "T_PC.PC_DATE_MES,T_PC.PC_COMM,T_PC.SERV_ID from T_COLLABORATEURS, T_PC" +
            $" where T_COLLABORATEURS.CO_ID = T_PC.CO_ID and T_PC.SERV_ID = '{service}' ", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dap.Fill(dt);
        PC_DT.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
```

Then on Datagrid SelectionChanged Event i can click on a row to get fields datas and put it in a texbox with this code :

```
// DataGrid SelectionChanged => Fill TexBox

           private void PC_DT_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PC_DT.SelectedItem is DataRowView oData)
        {
            string pcNom = (string)oData["PC_NOM"];
            string pcModel = (string)oData["PC_MODEL"];
            RefPcTxtBox.Text = $"{pcNom} / {pcModel}";
        }
    }
```

Now in a other application i want to use Linq To SQL to do exactly the same.

Fill DataGrid :

```
// Fill DataGrid
      private void GetPcListBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string service = (string)ServiceCB.SelectedValue;
        DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var pcCo = from co in dc.T_COLLABORATEURS
                   join pc in dc.T_PC on co.CO_ID equals pc.CO_ID
                   where pc.SERV_ID == service
                   select new
                   {
                       pc.PC_ID,
                       co.CO_IDENT,
                       pc.PC_NOM,
                       pc.PC_MODEL,
                       pc.PC_DATE_MES,
                       pc.PC_COMM,
                       pc.SERV_ID
                   };
        PC_DT.ItemsSource = pcCo;
    }
```

But now how can i fill my TextBox by clicking a DataGrid row ??

```
  private void PC_DT_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       // How to Fill my Textbox ??
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

**First way:**

```
// Or whenever grid you want to use please set this type
var Grid = sender as DataGrid; 
if(Grid != null)
{
  textbox  = Grid.FieldName
}
```

**Second way:**

```
var currentRow = GridName.SelectedRows;
if(currentRow != null)
{
  textbox  = currentRow .FieldName
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer but in thre First way, i get an error : "FieldName" does not exit in the current context

Comment: FieldName means which field display in textbox                                                     Ex:- Name (FieldName) then   var aa =Grid.Name